# How to use google assistant sdk/api from .net applications

Tags: .net, google-assistant-sdk

I have gone through the following google assist... documentation. Apart from being used in raspberry PI or by using Python,

1.can we use google assistant sdk in .net applications(windows & web)

2.or can we use by REST API services to communicate with google assistant API.

Comment: first look into this, google recommends grpc; the way to go is to bind from c# to grpc as in the link: https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use the Assistant SDK from .NET, although the directions for doing so are still very very sketchy.

In short, however, you will create the gRPC bindings from the protocol definition and use those bindings to send and receive audio to the Assistant service. There is no direct hotword support, although nothing is preventing you from doing that part yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to generate C# gRPC bindings for assistant from the following proto file https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2  but compiler not producing any .cs files, however its working for other files like helloworld.proto,primefacor.proto,... can it be any error preventing it from generating ,I'm clueless